# How to print a txt file in Python3 if it exists in a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Print a file to a default printer
last edited: June 2017
"""

import os
import sys
import subprocess
#import win32print

if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
    # linux
    lpr =  subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    lpr.stdin.write("This is a print-test sentence")
elif sys.platform == "darwin":
    # MAC OS X
    pass
elif sys.platform == "win32":
    # Windows
    os.startfile("C:/temp/temp.txt", "print")
```

I would like to know how to print a file `temp.txt` in Linux like in the Win example, how to print any `*.txt` file if it exists in the directory where the script (it should be only one) is and how to change encoding of that file (I need DOS 852 code page)?

Comment: Does current code print `This is a print sentence ` on linux

Comment: What about a try: open file, except: FileNotFoundError... do statement()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for file existence on any system, still the best inbuilt method is I think `os.path.isfile( filepath )`. If above code works for linux and windows you could do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Print a file to a default printer
last edited: June 2017
"""
import os
import sys
import subprocess
#import win32print

filepath = 'some_file_path'
if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
        # linux
        lpr =  subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        with open(filepath,'r') as file:
            lpr.stdin.write(file.read())

    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        # MAC OS X
        pass
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        # Windows
        os.startfile(filepath, "print")
```

Comment: Thanks for `with` suggestion. I just added `else` to the end to print to stdout if there is no file. Zahvaljujem!

Comment: Just one typo. It's not `stdio` but `stdin`

Comment: Corrected it :)